# vtkSTLReader reads only files in folder of execution

Tags: c++, vtk

NOTE: The question is invalid, I made an entirely different mistake, see edit at the end.

I want to simply read a STL file using the vtkSTLReader class. My code for that looks like this:

```
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkSTLReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSTLReader>::New();
        reader->SetFileName(path.c_str());
        reader->Update();
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> poly_data = reader->GetOutput();
```

and then the code proceeds to display the poly data.

This works to *some* degree. The code as it is will ignore anything in `path` except for the name of the file, and then look for that file at wherever I execute my program.

For example, if I go like `path = /home/local/users/myusername/file.stl`, have the program located at `/some_path/somefolder/myprogram` while calling it in the console being in `/some_path/`, it will only work if (and only if) there is a copy of the file at `/some_path/file.stl`.
Should I instead execute the program from within `/some_path/somefolder`, it will work only if there is `/some_path/somefolder/file.stl`.

I even went and tried what happens if I add a line of code

```
        path = "/dsgsdmklgmoeg/" + path;
```

and the outcome stays exactly the same.

As my paths suggest, I work under linux.
I tried stating an absolute path as above, a relative path from the place of execution and also a relative path from the executable (just in case).
For the relative path, I tried all sorts of variants of what I think it *might* want, with a leading `./`, with and without a leading `/`.
For the absolute path, I tried out replacing all slashes with backslashes, on the idea that it might use windows style paths.

I realize that a quick fix would be to simply copy the file to the required location, but that is surely not a permanent solution.

Has anybody had some experience with that? Is this some peculiarity of vtk?
If it is of importance, I use vtk 5.6.1 (and can't switch to a higher version due to some compatibility requirements).

Edit: I realized that I made a very simple mistake, instead of `path.c_str()` I had `file.c_str()` in my original code, with `file` being a variable from which `path` is assembled. I did not made the mistake when typing the code above, making the question invalid.

Comment: Is this only about STL files or can you reproduce your strange issue for other file types as well?

Comment: What type is `path`? Initially, I assumed `std::string` (due to `path.c_str()`) but actually it could have some kind of custom `FileName` type as well which is causing your issue.

Comment: @Scheff ad other file types: I tried it to some degree with VTK Legacy, with I think the same happening, but I haven't confirmed this. I might try this out in the future. ad type of `path`: I tried out both `string` and `QString`, no custom type. I also directly tried hard-coding the path at some point (so, pure `char*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I digged a bit into github.

This is what I found:

[`VTK/vtkSTLReader.cxx` at v5.6.1](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/v5.6.1/IO/vtkSTLReader.cxx) (`int vtkSTLReader::RequestData()`, lines 96 ... 110):

```
  if (!this->FileName || (this->FileName && (0==strlen(this->FileName))))
    {
    vtkErrorMacro(<<"A FileName must be specified.");
    this->SetErrorCode( vtkErrorCode::NoFileNameError );
    return 0;
    }

  // Initialize
  //
  if ((fp = fopen(this->FileName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
    vtkErrorMacro(<< "File " << this->FileName << " not found");
    this->SetErrorCode( vtkErrorCode::CannotOpenFileError );
    return 0;
    }
```

[`VTK/vtkSTLReader.h` at v5.6.1](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/v5.6.1/IO/vtkSTLReader.h) (lines 57 ... 60):

```
  // Description:
  // Specify file name of stereo lithography file.
  vtkSetStringMacro(FileName);
  vtkGetStringMacro(FileName);
```

[`VTK/vtkSetGet.h` at v5.6.1](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/v5.6.1/Common/vtkSetGet.h) (lines 88 ... 122):

```
//
// Set character string.  Creates member Set"name"() 
// (e.g., SetFilename(char *));
//
#define vtkSetStringMacro(name) \
virtual void Set##name (const char* _arg) \
  { \
  vtkDebugMacro(<< this->GetClassName() << " (" << this << "): setting " << #name " to " << (_arg?_arg:"(null)") ); \
  if ( this->name == NULL && _arg == NULL) { return;} \
  if ( this->name && _arg && (!strcmp(this->name,_arg))) { return;} \
  if (this->name) { delete [] this->name; } \
  if (_arg) \
    { \
    size_t n = strlen(_arg) + 1; \
    char *cp1 =  new char[n]; \
    const char *cp2 = (_arg); \
    this->name = cp1; \
    do { *cp1++ = *cp2++; } while ( --n ); \
    } \
   else \
    { \
    this->name = NULL; \
    } \
  this->Modified(); \
  } 

//
// Get character string.  Creates member Get"name"() 
// (e.g., char *GetFilename());
//
#define vtkGetStringMacro(name) \
virtual char* Get##name () { \
  vtkDebugMacro(<< this->GetClassName() << " (" << this << "): returning " << #name " of " << (this->name?this->name:"(null)")); \
  return this->name; \
  }
```

Looking at this code (which IMHO is the relevant code for OPs issue), I cannot find any hint that directories are stripped from a file path given by `SetFileName()`.

I've no idea what actually could cause the issue of OP that only files in the current directory are considered. However, I struggle to believe that VTK can be blamed for this.

So, I would recommend to search further above and below:

- above: Is the provided path in `SetFileName()` correct? (the easy part)
- below: Is this strange behavior caused by `fopen()` (or something which is called in `fopen()`)?

Comment: Ugh, and it just turned out that I made a mistake in the actual code, I had a variable file which contains just the file name and is then assembled into path and I used that other variable without realizing it, as it looked about right. My debug output used the correct variable and thus did not reveal the mistake. I even did not made that mistake when typing the code in my question. Anyway, thanks for digging into the code, actually made me reread my code resulting in me finding the error.

Comment: @Aziuth It was a welcome excuse to dig a bit in the VTK code (how they did things). It's satisfying that the weirdest effects usually have a simple reason - you just looked at the wrong end. (I've some personal experience about this.) Last but not least, it's amazing that my old mother is proved right once again: "Finally, you did something wrong." (Needless to say, that she doesn't know rather anything about computers.) ;-)